# XSLT version 1.0 need to pull out last word of string

Tags: xslt, xpath

I need to pull out the last word from the following string for the use of the surname:

```
<CUSTOMER_x0020_NAME>Mr Tim Cookson</CUSTOMER_x0020_NAME>
```

So I just need to pull out the 'Cookson' using XSLT, how do I do this? Tried several relations to substring-after but no luck.

Answer (score 2):

**Here is a non-recursive solution, which works with word delimiters that are any non-alphabetic characters** (but the characters after the last word, if any, should be only spaces):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:param name="pLower" select=
  "'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'"/>

 <xsl:param name="pUpper" select=
  "'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vAlpha" select="concat($pUpper, $pLower)"/>

 <xsl:template match="text()">
  <xsl:variable name="vText" select="normalize-space()"/>
  <xsl:variable name="vLength" select="string-length($vText)"/>
  <xsl:variable name="vPunct" select="translate(., $vAlpha, '')"/>

  <xsl:for-each select=
      "document('')//node()
      |document('')//@*
      |document('')//namespace::*">
   <xsl:variable name="vPos" select="position()"/>
   <xsl:variable name="vRemaining" 
                 select="substring($vText, $vPos)"/>

   <xsl:if test=
    "contains($vPunct, substring($vRemaining,1,1))
    and
     $vLength -$vPos 
       = string-length(translate($vRemaining, $vPunct, ''))
    ">
     <xsl:value-of select="substring($vRemaining,2)"/>
   </xsl:if>
  </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<CUSTOMER_x0020_NAME>Mr Tim Cookson</CUSTOMER_x0020_NAME>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
Cookson
```

**When the same transformation is applied on this XML document**:

```
<CUSTOMER_x0020_NAME>Mr. Tim Berners-Lee</CUSTOMER_x0020_NAME>
```

**again the correct result is produced:**

```
Lee
```

Comment: Very nice.  Dimitre, your deviousness and ingenuity never fail to inspire me.  (Those who like me seek to understand better how the black magic in this solution works may find it helpful to ask themselves what happens for strings whose last token begins more than 82 character into the space-normalized form of the string, and to ask themselves why that happens, and how to make it be some number other than 82.)

Comment: @C.M.Sperberg-McQueen, The answer to this question is in an article I wrote around 10 years ago: `<xsl:include href="file:///c:Shakespeare/Hamlet.xsl"/>` -- this contains enough nodes for a start :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this recursive template to get the last word of a value:

```
  <xsl:template name="GetLastWord">
    <xsl:param name="value" />
    <xsl:variable name="normalized" select="normalize-space($value)" />

    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="contains($normalized, ' ')">
        <xsl:call-template name="GetLastWord">
          <xsl:with-param name="value" select="substring-after($normalized, ' ')" />
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="$normalized"/>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
```

You would add this template to your XSLT, and then simply call it, like this:

```
  <xsl:call-template name="GetLastWord">
    <xsl:with-param name="value" select="CUSTOMER_x0020_NAME" />
  </xsl:call-template>
```

Comment: Thanks, that works great. How about if I was just pulling out the 'Tim' in Mr Tim Cookson for example?

Comment: What would be the criteria for selecting "Tim" in this case?  The first word after the first space?